# Is there a way to detect a mouse click with PyGTK AppIndicator

Tags: python, linux, gtk, pygtk, appindicator

I have a simple Python code that creates a Linux tray indicator with [AppIndicator3](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#AyatanaAppIndicator3-0.1/classes/Indicator.html) from [GI](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/api/api.html). That works fine. But I would like to detect and handle a simple user click or a double-click on this tray icon.

From what I know, for example, Telegram [uses](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/search?q=QSystemTrayIcon) Qt class [QSystemTrayIcon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html), and it supports this functionality because Telegram window shows itself when user double-clicks the tray icon.

- I know AppIndicator3 supports [`scroll_event`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#AyatanaAppIndicator3-0.1/classes/Indicator.html#AyatanaAppIndicator3.Indicator.signals.scroll_event) signal that triggers when the user scrolls mouse wheel over the tray icon.

> Signaled when the [`AyatanaAppIndicator3.Indicator`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/AyatanaAppIndicator3-0.1/classes/Indicator.html#AyatanaAppIndicator3.Indicator) receives a scroll event.

- There is also a [`set_secondary_activate_target(menuitem)`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#AyatanaAppIndicator3-0.1/classes/Indicator.html#AyatanaAppIndicator3.Indicator.set_secondary_activate_target) method that indicates there is somehow handled middle-click event.

> Set the `menuitem` to be activated when a secondary activation event
> (i.e. a middle-click) is emitted over the
> [`AyatanaAppIndicator3.Indicator`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/AyatanaAppIndicator3-0.1/classes/Indicator.html#AyatanaAppIndicator3.Indicator) icon/label.

Is there somebody who understands how it works? Both previous examples make me wonder why there is not a simple mouse click signal/event. I'm thinking if it could be possible to go deeper, maybe inherit [AyatanaAppIndicator3.Indicator](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#AyatanaAppIndicator3-0.1/classes/Indicator.html) class and rewrite some event handling? Or maybe dig even deeper into [StatusNotifierItem](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/StatusNotifierItem/StatusNotifierItem/) and [Activate](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/StatusNotifierItem/StatusNotifierItem/#activate) method, if it is what AppIndicator implements?

Or is there any *tricky* workaround for this? Because this seems to be an unanswered question for more than ten years and I am not satisfied with only the *"It is not possible"* answer.

I'm also aware I'm not the first one asking this question. I made small research and found multiple related threads:

[Python AppIndicator bindings -> howto check if the menu is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063743/python-appindicator-bindings-howto-check-if-the-menu-is-open)
[How to run an action when clicking on an appindicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224709/how-to-run-an-action-when-clicking-on-an-appindicator)
[How to program a one click indicator (add middle click functionality)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930848/how-to-program-a-one-click-indicator-add-middle-click-functionality)
[indicator-application does not send signals when a menu is shown/hidden](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libappindicator/+bug/522152) 
[handle click events and modifiers](https://github.com/AyatanaIndicators/libayatana-appindicator/issues/4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The perceived restrictions of AppIndicator are deliberate design choices (see Background information).

Listening to mouse click events will **not** work.

With AppIndicator you can have the following interactions:

- Primary action: Show a context menu (which may consist only of regular menu items, no arbitrary widgets can be placed).
- Secondary action: Activate one specific item in this context menu (usually middle mouse click on Desktops).
- Listen to mouse scroll events on the icon.

You will need to switch to another solution for detecting arbitrary mouse clicks. Here I assume you want to stick to Python/GTK as you tagged your question accordingly.

One solution is to use Gtk.StatusIcon which is based on the rather old [System Tray Protocol Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/systemtray-spec-0.3.html). Problem is this solution is slowly being phased out. It's marked deprecated in GTK3 and has been removed in GTK4.

The only other viable solution I know of is [libxapps](https://linuxmint-developer-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xapps.html#libxapp) (by Mint Linux). It features [XApp.StatusIcon](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#XApp-1.0/classes/StatusIcon.html) which has been specifically designed to be a modern replacement for Gtk.StatusIcon. It supports all Desktop Environments that can show tray icons.

**Background information**

The Ubuntu Desktop Experience Team deemed the Linux Desktop notification area a "problem-area". Specifically they criticized the inconsistency of different application status icon in user experience and style. They proposed to restrict user interactions to a few standardized ways. This effort led to the development of AppIndicator.
[(Source)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators)

By the way, here is another old (2011) albeit interesting blog post about different solutions:
[StatusNotifierItem (aka App Indicators) for Qt applications](https://agateau.com/2011/statusnotifieritem-for-qt-applications/)